# From Kosovo with a German residence permit, do I need a visa for the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, german-residents, kosovo-citizens

In December I want to visit the UK. I'm from Kosovo, but I have a German wife. We both want to go in December. I have a "Aufenthaltstitel" (Residence Permit) for 2 years, do I need a visa to go the UK?

I will appreciate it for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If your residence permit says "Aufenthaltskarte für Familienangehörige eines Unionsbürgers" then [you can travel without a visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card) as long as your wife accompanies you or is already in the UK when you enter.

Otherwise, you should apply for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).  This also has the condition that your wife accompany you or precede you to the UK.

To visit the UK without your wife, for most purposes, you would need a [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).